# Karate Framework for web automation

Tags: user-interface, karate

I have a scenario when automating the UI using karate. It all works well, however when a step fails the execution ends(karate closes the browser) and this leaves the system under test in a weird state. Is there a way to have a graceful exit, for instance if the step failed and the control could pass on to a clean up function or continue executing the next steps by having the browser still active, so that user can gracefully exit by clicking on the logout button ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without a [mcve] it is difficult for other users to know your un-graceful exit looks like. Please see [ask] and revise your question.

Answer (score 1):

Karate has [hooks](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) which can be used to address this clean up activity

Especially look for `afterScenario` configuration which can be helpful for implementing what needs to happen once the scenario is completed/failed.

This should have `driver` variable alive if it was properly initialized in your scenario. You can use that to implement any post action steps.

eg:

```
* configure afterScenario = 
 """ 
  function(){ 
   driver.click('input[name=logout]')
   driver.quit()
  } 
 """
```